# C# - Datagridview ocorre erro quando a célula da coluna fica vazia

Tags: c#

Peço por gentileza que algum programador experiente me ajude a solucionar este erro!
No código apresentado tem um cálculo de soma, o problema ocorre quando deixo uma das células da coluna do dgviewPersonalizado12 vazia, ocorrendo no seguinte erro, “datagridview System.InvalidCastException: 'Objeto não pode ser convertido de DBNull em outros tipos ”.

private void FrmTrimestre3_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
DgvCalculo();
PersonalizarDGV();
}

```
    private void PersonalizarDGV()
    {

        // largura das colunas
        dgviewPersonalizado12.Columns[0].Width = 64;
        dgviewPersonalizado12.Columns[1].Width = 105;
        dgviewPersonalizado12.Columns[2].Width = 64;
        dgviewPersonalizado12.Columns[3].Width = 105;
        dgviewPersonalizado12.Columns[4].Width = 64;
        dgviewPersonalizado12.Columns[5].Width = 105;
        dgviewPersonalizado12.Columns[6].Width = 64;
        dgviewPersonalizado12.Columns[7].Width = 105;
        dgviewPersonalizado12.Columns[8].Width = 64;
        dgviewPersonalizado12.Columns[9].Width = 105;
        dgviewPersonalizado12.Columns[10].Width = 64;
        dgviewPersonalizado12.Columns[11].Width = 105;
        dgviewPersonalizado12.ColumnHeadersVisible = false;
    }

    private void DgvCalculo()
    {

        var dcalculo = dgviewPersonalizado12;
        

        dgviewPersonalizado12.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
        dgviewPersonalizado12.ColumnHeadersVisible = false;
        dgviewPersonalizado12.ColumnCount = 12;
        dgviewPersonalizado12.RowCount = 7;
        // Nome das colunas
        dcalculo.Columns[0].Name = "Data";
        dcalculo.Columns[1].Name = "Semana1";
        dcalculo.Columns[2].Name = "Data";
        dcalculo.Columns[3].Name = "Semana2";
        dcalculo.Columns[4].Name = "Data";
        dcalculo.Columns[5].Name = "Semana3";
        dcalculo.Columns[6].Name = "Data";
        dcalculo.Columns[7].Name = "Semana4";
        dcalculo.Columns[8].Name = "Data";
        dcalculo.Columns[9].Name = "Semana5";
        dcalculo.Columns[10].Name = "Data";
        dcalculo.Columns[11].Name = "Semana6";

        // data hora     
        dcalculo.Columns["Data"].ValueType = typeof(DateTime);
        dcalculo.Columns["Data"].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "dd/MMM";



        dcalculo.Columns["Semana1"].ValueType = typeof(decimal);
        dcalculo.Columns["Semana1"].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "c";

        decimal total2 = 0;
        
        
            foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dcalculo.Rows)
            {
                total2 += Convert.ToDecimal(row.Cells["Semana1"].Value);
            }

            label20.Text = total2.ToString("c");
      
    }

   private void dgviewPersonalizado12_CellEndEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        DgvCalculo();           
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Precisa validar se o valor é nulo antes de somar, principalmente porque está convertendo, o que gera um `Exception` por estar null.

Pode por exemplo colocar um `if` antes de somar:

```
if (row.Cells["Semana1"] != null && row.Cells["Semana1"].Value !=  DBNull.Value)
{
    total2 += Convert.ToDecimal(row.Cells["Semana1"].Value);
}
```

Ou se quiser deixar o código fora do `if`, se for nulo, continua para a próxima linha:

```
if (row.Cells["Semana1"] == null || row.Cells["Semana1"].Value ==  DBNull.Value)
{
    continue;
}

total2 += Convert.ToDecimal(row.Cells["Semana1"].Value);
```

Comment: O código diz que o nome " row " não existe no contexto atual. Tem como resolver esse detalhe?

Comment: Você ta fazendo isso dentro do foreach?

Comment: Coloquei dentro do foreach, a "row" não dá mais erro o código roda, mas a mensagem de erro “datagridview System.InvalidCastException: 'Objeto não pode ser convertido de DBNull em outros tipos ”, infelizmente continua.

Comment: pode ter de precisar validar o valor tbm, atualizei a resposta

Comment: sim @NatanFernandes, dentro do foreach

Comment: Gente muito obrigado, Deus abençoe a todos, consegui!!! Não ocorre mais o erro, mas fiz essa pequena alteração que junto com a sua resolveu o problema.

Comment: A alteração foi o seguinte troquei o " null " pelo " DBNull.Value " e funcionou perfeitamente.

Comment: boa @MarcioValerio, vc tem razão, vou atualizar na pergunta :)